# Pra que serve o inherit e o initial do CSS?

Tags: css

Como o próprio título já diz, pra que serve o *inherit* e o *initial* que tem no CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Inherit*

*Inherit* significa simplesmente que o estilo será herdado do elemento pai.

De acordo com a própria [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inheriting) o **Inherit**:

> Especifica que uma propriedade deve herdar seu valor de seu elemento pai. A palavra *inherit* pode ser usada para qualquer propriedade *CSS*, e em qualquer elemento *HTML*.

Pode ler mais sobre o ***Inherit*** [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/inherit).

## Initial

*Initial* denota o valor inicial da propriedade, tal como definido nas [especificações CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords):

> Representa o valor especificado que é designado como o valor inicial da propriedade. A palavra initial pode ser usada para qualquer propriedade *CSS*, e em qualquer elemento *HTML*.

Resumidamente, ***Initial*** é usado para definir a propriedade *CSS* como seu valor padrão.

Você pode ver um exemplo do ***Initial*** [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/initial).

---

Formulei a resposta baseando me [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564650/what-does-inherit-mean-in-css) e [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534561/what-is-use-of-initial-value-in-css) questões do SO<sup>en</sup>, e utilizei tradução livre em algumas citações.

Comment: Este é um dos casos aonde a resposta de uma pergunta dup fica melhor que a resposta da primeira pergunta +1