# Como remover a borda do <input type="reset"> sem remover minha borda feita no css?

Tags: html, css

```css
#botoes {
  width: 270px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#botao {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  15px;
  font: bold 12px sans-serif;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
  border: 1px solid #9eb9c3;
  background: #edf6f9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#edf6f9', endColorstr='#cde5ee', GradientType=0);
  color: #527988;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10pc #c9c9c9
}

#botao:hover {
  background: #cde5ee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cde5ee', endColorstr='#edf6f9', GradientType=0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id=botoes>

  <div id="botao">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </div>

  <div id="botao">
    <input type="reset" name="limpar" value="Reset">
  </div>

  <div id="lembrar-senha">
    <input type="checkbox" />Lembrar senha
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta na primeira linha do seus CSS vc colocar assim

```
[type="reset"] {
  all: unset;
}
```

Para o `IE` vc pode fazer dessa forma já que ele não aceita o `unset` ([fonte](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value))

```
[type="reset"] {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

O importante é que esses estilos venham logo no início do seu CSS, antes dos estilos personalizados que vc colocou.

Dessa forma vc *reseta* todos os valores default desse tipo de input, depois vc coloca os estilos que vc deseja. **OBS:** Repare que eu não limpei os estilos do btn `type="submit"` para vc ver a diferença entre um e outro.

Veja o Exemplo aplicado com o seu código.

```css
/* reseta estilos desse input */
[type="reset"] {
  all: unset;
}
  
  #botoes{
width:270px;
margin-left:20px;

}
#botao{
float:right;
padding:5px 15px;
font: bold 12px sans-serif;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow:0px 1px 0px white;
border:1px solid #9eb9c3;

background: #edf6f9;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
background: linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#edf6f9', endColorstr='#cde5ee',GradientType=0 );
color:#527988;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10pc #c9c9c9
}

#botao:hover{
background: #cde5ee;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%,#edf6f9 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cde5ee 0%,#edf6f9 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cde5ee', endColorstr='#edf6f9',GradientType=0 );
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id=botoes>
      
  <div id="botao">      
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </div>
  
  <div id="botao">
        <input type="reset" name="limpar" value="Reset">
  </div>

    <div id="lembrar-senha">
      <input type="checkbox"/>Lembrar senha
    </div>

</div>
```

Existem outras formas de corrigir isso, mas essa eu acho a mais prítica, pois ele limpa os estilos do `user-agent` e vc pode começar "do zero" os estilos do seu elemento.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria estilizar o próprio elemento ao invés de criar um *wrapper* para o *reset*, isso só tende a complicar mais como você está aplicando a estilização nos elementos. A princípio, se tratando somente da borda que mencionou na pergunta, basta remover a borda (do elemento filho) e herdar os valores das propriedades `background` e `cursor` do elemento pai:

```
input[type='reset']{
  border: none;
  background: inherit;
  cursor: inherit
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre `inherit` [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205893/4808).

```css
#botoes {
  width: 270px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#botao {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  15px;
  font: bold 12px sans-serif;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
  border: 1px solid #9eb9c3;
  background: #edf6f9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#edf6f9 0%, #cde5ee 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#edf6f9', endColorstr='#cde5ee', GradientType=0);
  color: #527988;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10pc #c9c9c9
}

#botao:hover {
  background: #cde5ee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cde5ee 0%, #edf6f9 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cde5ee', endColorstr='#edf6f9', GradientType=0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='reset']{
  border: none;
  background: inherit;
  cursor: inherit
}
```

```html
<div id=botoes>

  <div id="botao">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </div>

  <div id="botao">
    <input type="reset" name="limpar" value="Reset">
  </div>

  <div id="lembrar-senha">
    <input type="checkbox" />Lembrar senha
  </div>
```

Comment: Jovem... só uma coisinha pra vc testar ai. Tenta colocar um padding de 50px nessa div, ou então muda a cor do gradiente do red para blue. Vc vai ver que o gradient erdado pelo input fica bugado, pois ele não tem a mesma altura do pai. O ideal seria mesmo remover a div envolta do input e estilizar o input, com o `inherit` o gradiente do filho não "casa" com o do pai

Comment: É esse o cenário que o AP colocou na pergunta dele?

Comment: Só fiz um comentário para vc testa ai jovem, da uma testadinha no que falei, como a cor do gradiente dele é suave fica difícil notar, mas se o gradiente for mais acentuado entre a primeira e a segunda cor vc vai ver que não fica legal. Faz o teste ai rapidão usa esse gradiente `linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, blue 100%)` vc vai ver que herdando o gradiente não fica com as cores alinhadas. O padding sugeri só pra ficar mais fácil de vc ver. Mas vc pode só testar com outra cor. De boa foi só um comentário pra vc testar e avaliar.

Comment: Também falei de boa. =)

Comment: Legal que vc levou na boa, é pq aqui tem gente que tem o ego nas alturas e não aceita nem comentário, ou nem para pra pensar 2x antes de sai negativando. Só dei a dica pq quando eu abri no meu monitor mesmo a cor sendo suave eu vi que deu uma quebra no gradiente, ai te sugeri fazer o teste. Se outra pessoa aplicar o exemplo com outras cores pode resultar em um efeito indesejado. Tmj